# Laravel 4 naming conventions for multiple word tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have searched but the other answers didn't help me at all. I have a table called : "hostess_types" and I have:

**Model:** HostessType.php

```
class HostessType extends Eloquent {
   protected $guarded = array();
   protected $table = 'hostess_types';

   public static $rules = array();
}
```

**Controller:** HostessTypesController.php

```
class HostessTypes extends BaseController {
     //controller stuff
}
```

**Views:** they are in views/hostess_types/

**Route:**

```
Route::resource('hostess_types', 'HostessTypesController');
```

When I navigate to mywebsite.com/hostess_types I get:

```
ReflectionException

Class HostessTypesController does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller name to HostessTypesController.

```
class HostessTypesController extends BaseController {
     //controller stuff
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I missed that, I feel so stupid. Error is gone now, thanks a ton.

Comment: Yeah sorry I had to wait one minute :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to pass controller after contoller name.so You should use

```
class HostessTypesController extends BaseController {
 //controller stuff
 }
```

instead of

```
class HostessTypes extends BaseController {
 //controller stuff
 }
```